# how to move separately two UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgpoint

I have two UIImageView in the same view,I would like to move them but separately.When I move the first one,the second one should stay fix and conversely.

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location  = [touch locationInView:[self view]];
    [imageView1 setCenter:location];

    [imageView2 setCenter:location];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this method is a method from UIResponder class will and will be called when the UIView (UIImageView is a subclass so no problem) is moved.

What you have to do, is subclass `UIImageView` and don't implement this method in your superview.

**MovableImageView.h**

```
@interface MovableImageView : UIImageView {
```

}

**MovableImageView.m**

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location  = [touch locationInView:[self view]];
    [self setCenter:location];
}
```

Each one of your two `UIImageView` should now be `MovableImageView`

Comment: To be precise, it's a UIResponder method, not a UIView method.

Comment: I am not able to to set the locationInView to self view since we are in the UIImageView.And when I remove the view and I keep self.The UIImageView moves oddly